# How to recreate the user_picture field?

Tags: 8, theming, entities, installation

On Drupal 8 there is by default a user_picture field for the user's photo. When I started my site several months ago, I deleted this field because I did not use it.

[image]

Today I need this field, so I created an image type field.

[image]

**MY PROBLEM :** I installed some modules that use the user's photo, but it can not be found because the user_picture is the default

If I create a user_picture field it automatically adds field_ in front of the machine name.

Is it possible to restore the default field with the correct machine name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of importing configuration as suggested previously, you could as an alternative, programmatically re-create the field. Here is some code that does that.

```
<?php

use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;


// Create the user profile field and instance.
FieldStorageConfig::create([
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'field_name' => 'user_picture',
  'type' => 'image',
  'translatable' => '0',
])->save();
FieldConfig::create([
  'label' => 'User Picture',
  'description' => '',
  'field_name' => 'user_picture',
  'entity_type' => 'user',
  'bundle' => 'user',
  'required' => 0,
])->save();
```

Assuming the code above is placed in a file called `recreateUserPicture.php` that is stored in your docroot, you can run the following Drush command:

```
drush scr recreateUserPicture.php
```

Best of luck!

N.B.: An alternative answer (since the importing of configuration from the standard profile has a problem with having the field being available in Views UI).

Comment: @1ad9ac48, you must delete the `user_picture` field before running the code above.

Comment: You can easily run this code by pasting into the interactive shell from running "drush php"

Comment: That was useful Mr. Petrakis ;)

Comment: A pleasure to hear that Mr. Upsidown!

Answer (score 5):

This can be handled using the install configuration that the standard profile holds. Easiest way would be using drupal's console, that would mean following these steps (from inside your docroot):

1. `drupal config:import:single --file=core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.storage.user.user_picture.yml`
2. `drupal config:import:single --file=core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.field.user.user.user_picture.yml`
3. `drupal update:entities`

In case you can't work on the terminal using drupal console, you can import these two configuration from the administrative interface. This can be found under the `admin/config/development/configuration/single/import` URL (relative to your host's name).
From there, you need to import twice, one time the file storage configuration (contents of core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.storage.user.user_picture.yml) and the second would be the file configuration (contents of core/profiles/standard/config/install/field.field.user.user.user_picture.yml).

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you I updated the question. It does not work

Comment: Did you try using the admin interface?

Comment: There is a problem. The field has been recreated, but it is not available in the views. An idea ?

Comment: @1ad9ac48, I can reproduce that issue. I haven't figured out why Views does not make the field available. I posted an alternative answer that solves your issue in a programmatic way.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, according to the tips above, wanted to go a save way, for me the following solution helped:

1. `drush cex` to export my actual configuration into Yaml files
2. compared them with the original files (by searching (..vendor/drupal/core/profiles/standard/config/install) --> by using the grep command in linux e.g. `grep -Ril 'user_picture' /vendor/drupal/core/profiles/standard/config/install`
3. edited the following files of my exported configuration Yaml files:

   ```
   +------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+

   | Collection | Config                                     | Operation |

   +------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+

   |            | field.storage.user.user_picture            | Create    |

   |            | field.field.user.user.user_picture         | Create    |

   |            | core.entity_view_display.user.user.default | Update    |

   |            | core.entity_view_display.user.user.compact | Update    |

   |            | core.entity_form_display.user.user.default | Update    |

   +------------+--------------------------------------------+-----------+
   ```
4. `drush cim` to reimport the modified and added files
5. `drush cr` to clear cache

Tip: maybe its already enough to copy the two files:
field.storage.user.user_picture and field.field.user.user.user_picture and to your config export directory (after a fresh export) and do an import, because the difference within the core files was just a missing dependency.